# Does netTcpBinding work without WAS?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

Just for clarification and a simple yes or no will do, but can IIS host net.tcp binding (non-HTTP support) without Windows Process Activation Service (WAS)?

Is it possible, or is WAS compulsory to use net.tcp binding in IIS?

Thaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WAS is essential. For anything other than http/https.

But it is built-in in the latest versions of IIS.

Comment: Can you look at this? There is no mention of WAS. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/james_osbornes_blog/archive/2010/12/07/hosting-in-iis-using-nettcpbinding.aspx

Comment: But I do see "Non-HTTP Activation" a few times. But it depends on several versions, list yours.

Answer (score 1):

NO, Non-HTTP activation is not possible w/o WAS. Alternate is to self-host WCF service in Managed application or Managed service.